# Include logging in Elvis operator?

Tags: kotlin

As far as I can see, the only way to use the elvis operator is with syntax like this:

```
foo = bar ?: return
```

I was curious if anyone has come up with a way to include logging, as generally the return is used (at least in my experience) when something does not behave as expected.

However, the following syntax is invalid:

```
foo = bar ?: {
   Log.e(TAG, "Some error occurred.")
   return
}
```

Of course I could simply do the following,

```
foo = bar
if (foo == null) {
   Log.e(TAG, "Some error occurred.")
   return
}
```

but is there any way of including logging with the Elvis operator?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just use the [`run { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) function from `kotlin-stdlib`, which runs the lambda it is passed:

```
foo = bar ?: run { 
    Log.e(TAG, "Some error occurred.")
    return
}
```

Comment: Yeah, we are the same. but I use `let`. your `return` should be put it outside, which will be more clearly.

Comment: I think this or David Furman's answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

The `{}` is a lambda, you should invoke it, for example:

```
//                   v--- it is a lambda
foo = bar ?: return  {
    Log.e(TAG, "Some error occurred.")
}() // <--- invoke the lambda
```

**OR** invoke a lambda with `let`:

```
foo = bar ?: return let{
    Log.e(TAG, "Some error occurred.")
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `run`? There is no free `let` function. It must be invoked on an object. Also, I find it not very idiomatic to create a function and then immediately invoke it like that. Using `run` is the idiomatic way imo.

Comment: @marstran I never say `run` is a bad way, I said  I use `let` to invoke a lambda.

Comment: But `let` doesn't work like you describe here. It is not a "free" function. You have to invoke it on an object like `someObject.let { ... }`.

Comment: @marstran I know it. It doesn't matter. I already told you consider more is not a bad thing. there are many ways do the same thing in Kotlin. Why should I be so rigid? have you remember your previous answer ? you use `let`, I use `apply`, but we do the same thing.

Comment: why doesn't work like you describe here? have you seen the variable definition? it can be a variable / property. I'd like to say the code above is just a piece of code snippets. I'm not good at english, stop to talking about it. :)

Comment: This snippet doesn't compile: `foo = bar ?: return let{ Log.e(TAG, "Some error occured.") }`. That is the problem. The `let` function needs to be called on an object. You can not use `let` this way, so I wonder how you actually do it. ;)

Comment: @marstran Why we can? you can't, you must ask yourself. the first statement  `foo = bar ?: return` in the question is already told you the code snippet must be in a function.

Comment: Yes, I did it in a function and I declared bar and foo properly. Now, I get `Unresolved reference: let`. There is no function `let` that can be called that way!

Comment: @martran I already said  `foo` can be a field/ property. have you see any variable definition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149753/discussion-between-marstran-and-holi-java).

Answer (score 1):

Oh, all you have to do is this:

```
foo = bar ?: kotlin.run {
   Log.e(TAG, "Some error occurred.")
   return
}
```

This may be arguably less readable than a standard if null check, but hey at least here's how you do it.